# Linux Mint 21 and Windows 11 dual partition fiasco on Lenovo Ideapad

Tags: linux-mint, linux-kernel, windows, dual-boot, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed Linux Mint 21 on my Lenovo Ideapad this morning alongside Windows 11. It was successful and everything was working perfectly. Until my root partition for Linux was nearly full and I decided to resize it by firstly removing existing Linux OS from my system and then reinstalling it with a fresh copy but with enhanced storage capacities.

I deleted some partitions in Windows to achieve this but I accidentally deleted something important causing Boot Device missing error when my computer restarted. Now although I have reinstalled Linux and it is working fine, I can't access my Windows OS. I tried fixing it with a bootable USB for Windows 11 but it is not recognizing my original Windows 11 OS. I can't seem to repair the Windows OS using Windows Startup repair tool either. It is not working.

What to do now?
Please help!

Comment: Post this so we can see what is where: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ Boot-Repair only fixes Linux boot issues (mostly by reinstalling grub). If Windows issues, you will need your Windows repair/recovery flash drive. And may need good backups, if  you have to reinstall & restore from backups.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to repair the Windows bootloader using either a Boot-Repair live USB or a Rescatux live USB.

### Boot Repair

From Linux Mint open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair  
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install -y boot-repair
sudo boot-repair
```

Open the Boot Repair application and select *Advanced Options* -> *Other Options* tab -> *Repair Windows boot files*. The boot flag should be placed on the same partition on which Mint is installed. The partition on which Mint is installed can be identified from the built-in Disks application.

[image]

If you're unable to select the *Repair Windows boot files* option because it's grayed out, refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947346/how-do-i-boot-windows-10-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-3/947628#947628).

---

### Rescatux

[Rescatux](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/) is a free bootable live CD/USB that can repair GRUB and the Windows bootloader. Rescatux has a graphical interface with a menu of operating system rescue tasks. If your hard disk has the MBR partitioning format, you can select the *Restore Windows MBR (BETA)* option to repair the Windows bootloader. If your computer has UEFI firmware, you can select among the UEFI boot options.

**Boot options:**

- (>=0.41 beta 1) Update UEFI order
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Create a new UEFI Boot entry
- (>=0.41 beta 1) UEFI Partition Status
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Fake Microsoft Windows UEFI
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Hide Microsoft Windows UEFI
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Reinstall Microsoft Windows EFI
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Check UEFI Boot

**GRUB options:**

- (>=0.40 beta 11) Easy GNU/Linux Boot Fix
- Restore GRUB and GRUB2
- (>=0.31 beta 4) Update any GRUB2 menu
- Update Debian/Ubuntu GRUB menus

**Windows options:**

- Restore Windows MBR (BETA)
- Clear Windows passwords
- (>=0.31 beta 4) Promote a Windows user to Administrator role
- (>=0.41 beta 1) Reinstall Microsoft Windows EFI
- (>=0.31 beta 4) Unlock Windows user

**Password options:**

- Change GNU/Linux Password
- Regenerate sudoers file
- Clear Windows passwords

**Expert tools:**

- Boot-Repair
- GParted
- OS-Uninstaller
- Clean-Ubiquity
- PhotoRec
- TestDisk

[image]
<sup>**Rescapp is a nice wizard that will guide you through your rescue tasks.**</sup>

---

### How to make a Rescatux live USB from Linux Mint

1. Install GParted partition editor with `sudo apt install gparted`.
2. Insert a USB flash drive and check if the boot flag has been enabled on the flash drive using the GParted application. Unmount the USB flash drive. Open GParted and select the USB flash drive from the menu list of drives. From the GParted menu select: *Partition* -> *Manage Flags* -> check *boot*.
3. It is **very important** to verify that the device that you are installing the Rescatux live USB to is indeed your flash drive, so that you don't overwrite any of your system or personal files which may make your operating system unbootable. In Mint you can find the device name of the flash drive using the *Disks* application.
4. Unmount the USB partition device. Let's say the USB partition device is `/dev/sdc1`

   ```
    sudo umount /dev/sdc1 # replace sdc1 with the partition name of your USB drive
   ```
5. Change directories using `cd` to the path of the directory where the Rescatux iso file that you downloaded is located.
6. Write the Rescatux iso file to the USB flash drive. In the following command replace `rescatux_0.xxxx.iso` with the name of the Rescatux iso file you downloaded.

   ```
    sudo dd if=rescatux_0.xxxx.iso of=/dev/sdc # this command also works in Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 
    sudo sync
   ```

I have also been able to make a Rescatux live USB using the built-in USB Image Writer app.